# Gmail Actions Whitelisting Process: Unsubscribe Link Requirement

Tags: google-schemas

As part of the whitelisting process for the Gmail Actions, is an unsubscribe link required to be in the email if the audience is internal (only employees)?

We currently use Google Apps (and thus Gmail) for our enterprise mail. We would like to implement the Gmail actions in our issue tracking system's email notifications. The only people that receive these emails are other employees but we need to ensure that 1) people cannot unsubscribe from notifications for themselves and 2) if the notification is sent to a distribution list, not unsubscribe for the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unsubscribe link is not required but please describe your use case with the form linked from https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google and note that you are only interested in sending emails internally to your domain.